# Parallel port IRQ Handler registration on IRQ7

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, archlinux

I have written one device driver of parallel port driver with IRQ handler.

Now, first i must have to access IRQ7 because my parallel port gives interrupt on it(I had seen that on /proc/interrupts).

Now, the problem that i faced is my request_irq() function fails whenever i am trying to request for irq7.

Also, my cat /proc/interrupt is looks like::

CPU0 CPU1
0:         98          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
1:      11764       2178   IO-APIC-edge      i8042

3:          2          0   IO-APIC-edge
4:          2          0   IO-APIC-edge
  7:          8          0   IO-APIC-edge      parport0

8:          1          0   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0

9:          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi

Where i don't know what is parport0.
As per my thinking, because of this parport0 my request_irq fails.

I had read that:
The `parport' code provides parallel-port support under Linux.  This includes the ability to share one port between multiple device drivers. You can pass parameters to the parport code to override its automatic detection of your hardware.  This is particularly useful if you want to use IRQs, since in general these can't be autoprobed successfully. By default IRQs are not used even if they *can* be probed.  This is because there are a lot of people using the same IRQ for their parallel port and a sound card or network card.

So, how can i register my interrupt handler on irq7 so that i can manage interrupts from parallel port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a parallel port driver installed on your system. That's why kernel fails to assign irq for your driver. First, unload the current parallel driver then try again.

Comment: How can i unload?? can you please give me steps?
And is it default driver??

Comment: And also,, they told that if more user are there then they always share irq7. so how can it possible?

Comment: use rmmod command to unload parport module. Something like: 
          "rmmod parportmodulename"
try it!

Comment: why? rmmod failed? or some other reason?

Comment: it will give me error that it's in use.
and it is not that of dynamically loaded

Comment: look at cat /proc/interrupts output. IRQ7's row the rightmost entry has the parportmodule name (most probably "parport0", the output you posted on question). Then recheck it with lsmod output.

Comment: the name at that place in cat /proc/interrupts are name given by us...and i will post the outputs.

Comment: lsmod have not any parport0.

Comment: whatever the module name is from cat /proc/interrupts, unload it and try again.

Comment: lsmod has 1) parport,, 2) parport_pc,, 3) ppdev

Comment: if i do,,,,, rmmod parport, then output is....)))ERROR: Module parport is in use by ppdev,parport_pc,lp

Comment: But i don't understand what to unload so that i will access IRQ7.

Comment: You already have a driver for your parport, isn't it? And parport has dependencies, ppdev,parport_pc,lp they're dependent on parport. You can force to remove parport using "rmmod -f parport" or can unload ppdev, parport_pc,lp first, then try parport to unload.

Comment: ok. i had unloaded lp, ppdev, parport_pc and then successfully parport

Comment: so, i have nomore parport0 in cat /proc/interrupts

Comment: No, lp, ppdev, parport_pc they were using parport module i.e parallel port.

Comment: prob1: that will gives unknown symbols like parport_register, unregister(),, etc..
And after reboot the parport0 exist at /proc/interrupts IRQ7..

Comment: Please, don't guess. Check, verify and proceed. You can't have a double handler for a single IRQ. Try to clear up your concept of kernel module, device driver etc. Reread the documents again.

Comment: as per i know,,, single IRQ has more handler. In request_irq() function there is flag called IRQF_SHARED which will make it shared and at a time which handler it will use that will depend on last parameter(dev id).

Comment: Ok, you're right. But did you passed IRQF_SHARED while registering the IRQ?

Comment: Yes, i had passed it. But i am confused what to pass in device id as a last parameter. And i used IRQF_SHARED with random device id which will failed.

Comment: Passing NULL when using IRQF_SHARED is error according to concept.
What i am thinking is, first i remove lp, ppdev, parport_pc and then parport0. Then if i want to load lp, ppdev, parport_pc then what should i do?? because after that file will loaded then and then my driver get support for parallel port.

Comment: Well, when you start writting interrupt handler for first time, you won't love to have much complicacy. That's why I suggest you to remove the existing module and try. And, to load module use - insmod (already mentioned on prev comnt).

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you check the return code for request_irq. It will tell you the reason for failure. Chances are that, as rakib noted, parport0 - the default driver - is installed. You can try to register a SHARED IRQ handler - that should work : Most IRQs are shareable (SA_SHIRQ flag). Also remember not to pass a NULL pointer as your device ID.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I had used that SA_SHIRQ, and tried but it did not worked.